# Change specific icon's color in NavigationDrawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-navigationview

I have a problem with changing the icon's color in default Drawer Menu in Android, there are lots of topics but they only explain changing the tint color of whole menu not a specific icon:

[image: Menu Items]

For example I want to change the color of Favorites icon to yellow

Comment: you want to change it for permanent, I mean you want to show your favorites color by default yellow?

Comment: yes exactly i wanna put different color for different item

Comment: as @Burhanuddin answer, you can change your icon color by replacing default icon to colored icon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change icon of the menu from here like this from `activity_drawer_drawer.xml` layout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_camera"
                <!-- Change your drawable here -->
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
                android:title="Import"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
                android:title="Gallery"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
                android:title="Slideshow"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_manage"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
                android:title="Tools"/>
        </group>

        <item android:title="Communicate">
            <menu>
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/nav_share"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
                    android:title="Share"/>
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/nav_send"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
                    android:title="Send"/>
            </menu>
        </item>

    </menu>
```

To remove tint color effect use this

```
mNavigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
```

Comment: yes but it is not the issue i was talking about color not changing the icon

Comment: i have edited my answer use `mNavigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);` to remove tint color effect and show your original image color

Comment: thanks it worked but is there any way to do it by style and xml?

Comment: with androidx libraries you can use `app:iconTint="@color/primaryDarkColor"` even for older apis